# Submitting form with ajax and reloading location to current tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a web page with a few different tabs, some with forms. On successful submission of any form, I am reloading the page, but it keeps going to the default first tab. I am trying to set a storage variable to help toggle if it is the first time loading the page (open the default tab) or is being reloaded via form submission (pass that tab's id as variable and load it on reload)

How can I successfully reload on a specific tab?

Below is the form submission function with ajax I am calling

```
    //submit all forms on page
    const submitForm = (formID, targetTab) => {
        let theForm = document.getElementById(formID);

        //function will determine whichform is being passed and send data to PHP page
        //on reload trying to detect current tab and load to that location
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(theForm).attr("action"),
            data: $(theForm).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload()
                initFunction(targetTab)
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the function handling which tab to reload, I call it initially on pageload, is that where the problem is?

```
   const initFunction = (tab) => {
        let reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
        if (!reloading) {
            document.getElementById(tab).click();
            sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", 'true');
        } else {
            document.getElementById(tab).click();
        }
    };

    //clicks on default first tab
    window.onload = initFunction('defaultOpen');
```

Here is an example of my nav tab buttons and a one of the form submission buttons

```
//nav
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link bg-primary tabLink text-white" href="#" id="defaultOpen" 
         onclick="changeTab(event, 'companytab')">
        <i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;Company</a>
     </li>

   <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link bg-primary tabLink text-white" href="#"
          onclick="changeTab(event, 'contacttab')" id="contacttabbtn">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;Contacts</a>
  </li>

//button 
   <button onclick="submitForm('updateProspect', 'defaultOpen')"
              id="saveBtn"class="float-right d-none btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"> 
              </i>&nbsp;Save
   </button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to pass the tab's ID to the PHP as a parameter and return it from the script. Then you can reach it in response (success: {}) in the ajax form. And after that you can manipulate the tabs however you want with the returned ID from the PHP script.